# VB.net closing folder - doesn't work when IE open

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Sort of an odd problem I'm encountering.

Im using the following code to find an open folder and close it

```
Dim sh = CreateObject("shell.application")
For Each item In sh.Windows
    If item.document.folder.self.Path = DBFolder Then
        item.Quit()
    End If
Next
```

Here's the weird part, it works as intended unless an Internet Explorer window is open.  With IE open I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMemberException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Public member 'folder' on type
>   'HTMLDocumentClass' not found.

I don't personally use IE but my users probably do so this is going to cause issues if I deploy.  Does anyone have a workaround or suggestion?

Comment: Turn **Option Strict On** and fix your errors. Then get rid of the old vb6 **CreateObject**. Then fix those errors, should be `late binding` errors. Use the replacement for CreateObject, it is the System.Activator. CreateInstance method.

Comment: @Codexer his problem is that he is looping both explorer and internet explorer windows.  There is no "item.document.folder" member for an IE window.

Comment: I know what the exact problem is but he needs to fix other issues first. If he does then the debugger would show him exactly the problem. Your missing the point of my comment...

Comment: @Codexer Yes, good point on option strict

Comment: On another note you are dealing with COM objects, make sure you properly handle them, otherwise the garbage wont be taken out.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, you will be picking up any open explorer or internet explorer windows.  You can handle this by adding a reference to `mshtml` in Microsoft HTML Object Library and also `SHDocVw` in Microsoft Internet Controls.

`Add Reference > COM > Type Libraries > Microsoft HTML Object Library`

`Add Reference > COM > Type Libraries > Microsoft Internet Controls`

```
    Dim sh As New SHDocVw.ShellWindows

    For Each item In sh

        If Not TypeOf item.Document Is mshtml.HTMLDocument Then
            MessageBox.Show("it is not an IE window! " + item.Path())
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("it is an IE window!" + item.Path())
        End If


    Next item
```

Comment: Theres no need to add all of this, he already has the object. Why not just check the type of object first? If its HTMLDocumentClass skip it... this evidentially is not a directory.

Comment: @Codexer Maybe i'm missing something here.. he needs ShDocVw so he can instantiate the shell and get rid of CreateObject() and he needs mshtml so he can check the type of item.Document